# How to repair the system path on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: terminal, path, command

> drewjr@Andrews-MacBook-Pro ~ % echo $PATH
> /Users/drewjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/bin:/Users/drewjr/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0@global/bin:/Users/drewjr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/drewjr/.rvm/bin:/Users/drewjr/.rvm/bin:/Users/drewjr/.rvm/bin:/Users/drewjr/.rvm/bin:/Users/drewjr/.rvm/bin

So I was trying to learn some things in terminal and I messed up my path, I am looking for some help to try to fix this mess.

Comment: What problem are you having with your system path? Can you do ordinary commands like ls, touch, etc.?

Comment: Yes I can do thouse commands it seems to work for basic commands.

Comment: OK, what commands don't work?